# Application of the Löwenheim-Skolem Theorem

Tags: logic, set-theory, model-theory

In the lecture notes I'm currently reading, the professor wrote that an application of the Löwenheim-Skolem theorem (stated below) is to show that the theory of infinite vector spaces over a field $K$ in the language $\mathcal{L} = (0, +, (f_q)_{q \in K})$ is complete. Here $f_q$ are the unary functions to be understood like scalar-multiplication by $q$ in the vector space.

My confusion is: The Löwenheim-Skolem theorem makes a statement about the existence of models of a certain size. Why would that help? To apply Löwenheim-Skolem I need the theory to be consistent anyway - and can't I then just directly apply Gödel's completeness theorem?

**Theorem (Löwenheim-Skolem (ZFC)):** Let $T$ be a consistent theory with infinite models in a language $\mathcal{L}$ of cardinality $\kappa$. Then for any infinite cardinal $\lambda \geq \kappa$ the theory $T$ admits a model of size $\lambda$.

Comment: You probably mean Löwenheim-Skolem

Comment: Oh boy, thanks! I've been studying the topic for a while now and I always misread it...

Comment: There is also some confusion between "completeness" and "concistency". The L-S thm assume concistency and does not say anything about completeness.

Comment: Ah, I see! I confused completeness with coherency of a theory, so Gödel's theorem isn't going anywhere.

Comment: If remember well, Gödel completeness theorem says that some syntatic calculus is complete: if you cannot derive inconsistencies, then there is a model. Completeness of a theory is a different notion.

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First let me address your confusion over why Lowenheim-Skolem is necessary. The theory of a class $\mathbb{K}$ of structures is the set of sentences satisfied by all structures in that class. Unlike the theory of a *single* structure, **this theory need not be complete** - for instance, if $\mathbb{K}$ is the class of groups, then the commutativity axiom "$\forall x, y(x*y=y*x)$" is not in $Th(\mathbb{K})$ (since there are non-abelian groups), but neither is its negation (since there are abelian groups).

So we can't just automatically conclude that the theory in your question is complete; we need to argue that any two structures in your class are "basically the same" (= elementarily equivalent). A standard trick for doing this is: given $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$ which we want to show are elementarily equivalent, build "bigger" structures $\mathcal{A}'$ and $\mathcal{B}'$, such that we know $\mathcal{A}\equiv\mathcal{A}'$ and $\mathcal{B}\equiv\mathcal{B}'$, and show that $\mathcal{A}'\cong\mathcal{B}'$. Do you see a way to use Lowenheim-Skolem to do this, here? *HINT: what determines the isomorphism type of a vector space? How is this related to its cardinality?*

---

Incidentally, re: the strategy above, a neat theorem of Keisler and Shelah gives a way to do this that always works: if $\mathcal{A}\equiv\mathcal{B}$, then they have isomorphic ultrapowers (and obviously conversely)! This is Theorem 10.7 of [this survey article on ultraproducts by Keisler](https://ms.mcmaster.ca/~hanj18/jessewebpage_files/keisler-ultraproducts.pdf), which is valuable reading if you're interested in the more set-theoretic side of model theory.

Comment: The fact that "if $A$ and $B$ are elementary equivalent then they have isomorphic ultrapowers" has some hypotheses, doesn't it ? I vaguely remember seeing that what's always true is that they have isomorphic ultralimits, or that one embeds in an ultrapower of the other; and that in some specific cases they have isomorphic ultrapowers

Comment: @Max Nope, it's correct as written; you can find it as [Theorem 10.7 in this survey article of Keisler](https://ms.mcmaster.ca/~hanj18/jessewebpage_files/keisler-ultraproducts.pdf). Maybe you're thinking of Keisler's earlier result, which assumed GCH?

Comment: Actually I read it in Grätzer's _Universal Algebra_, but he only says "it hasn't been proved without the GCH yet", so maybe it's a bit outdated.

Comment: @Max Yes, that book was written before Shelah's paper. Shelah proved the theorem in 1972; Gratzer's first edition was 1968.

Comment: Ok, well it's always good to know new theorems, thank you for pointing that out :-)

Comment: I think I worked out how it works: Let $\kappa$ be the cardinality of the field $K$. The Löwenheim-Skolem theorem tells me that there is a vector-space (a model) $V$ of cardinality $\lambda$ for any infinite cardinal $\lambda \geq \kappa$. The dimension of $V$ must be $\lambda$, as its cardinality is $\lambda = \kappa \dim V$. Hence any two vector spaces of cardinality $\lambda$ are isomorphic. But any two infinite vector-spaces $W, U$ can be embedded into a larger space (and thus we have a $\omega$-isomorphism, giving elementary equivalence). Is that correct?

Comment: @Steven That's basically right, although there's a snappier way. (i) Show that any infinite vector space elementarily embeds into an infinite-dimensional one. (This isn't trivial - an infinite vector space can be finite dimensional, and will be if $K$ is infinite - but is easy: use the compactness theorem.) So it's enough to show that any two infinite-dimensional vector spaces are e. e. (ii) Say $U, V$, are of infinite dimensions $\kappa_0$ and $\kappa_1$ respectively. WLOG $\kappa_0\le\kappa_1$. By LS, $U$ e.e.s into $U'$ with dimension $\kappa_1$; but $U'$ and $V$ have the same dimension ...